# RAID1: Migrate HDD to SSD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssd, raid1

My current workstation uses an Adaptec 5805, with Win2008 mirrored between two 72 GB (10K?) savvio drives.

My question is if there's a way to migrate the mirror to use SSDs - I've been looking at 90GB Corsair Force (Sandy Bridge) to replace the existing setup.  If it's possible, without installing the OS fresh.

If I replaced the mirrored drive with an SSD, would the array sync the drives?  Then I could promote the SSD mirror to be the primary, and use the second SSD as the mirror.  That'd be too easy...

Or should use Ghost to get an image of the existing setup, apply it to the SSD for a new mirror to be setup on?

Answer (score 1):

> If I replaced the mirrored drive with
>   an SSD, would the array sync the
>   drives?

Yes. And it should turn it into a hybrid raid. No need to use a second SSD then, pretty much. Adaptec has special support for hybrid RAID 10 / mirrors. ALl writes go to both discs, all (!) reads only to the SSD. Cheaper, nearly same perforamnce unless you do a lot of writes, which you normall dont on a OS.

But the old disc somewhere else and kill the parittions then, then you can reuse it ;)

Comment: These Adaptec Hybrid RAID still don't appear to support TRIM so you will see degredation in speed compared to a single SSD.

Comment: I want the RAID array to be a matched pair of drives, ultimately.

Comment: So you like wasted money? No joke - Adapted has some very interesting white papers re performance of hybris drives.